# Simple Deque initialization question

Tags: c++

I have used the following code to insert some data in a deque.

```
int data[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};   
deque<int> rawData (data, data + sizeof(data) / sizeof(int));
```

But I dont understand this part of the code,

```
data + sizeof(data) / sizeof(int)
```

What does it mean?

Comment: There's nothing subjective about this, but if I answer it here I won't have to answer it when it's migrated to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question is good but definitely belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: I thought for programming related question this is where I should come first. Why this question belongs to StackOverflow?

Comment: StackOverflow is about code itself, and programmers.stackexchange.com is about the profession.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take that bit by bit.

`data` is the iterator showing where to start.  It's an array, but in C and C++ arrays decay to pointers on any provocation, so it's used as a pointer.  Start taking in data from `data` on, and continue until the end iterator.

The end iterator is a certain amount past the start iterator, so it can be expressed as `data + <something>`, where `<something>` is the length.  The start iterator is an `int []` that is treated as an `int *`, so we want to find the length in `int`s.  (In C and C++, pointers increment by the length of the pointed-to type.)

Therefore, `sizeof(data) / sizeof(int)` should be the length of the array.  `sizeof(data)` is the total size of the array in bytes.  (This is one of the differences between arrays and pointers:  arrays have a defined size, while pointers point to what might be the start of an array of unknown size.)  `sizeof(int)` is the total size of an int in bytes, and so the quotient is the total size of `array` in `int`s.

We want the size of `array` in `int`s because `array` decays into an `int *`, and so `data + x` points to the memory location x `int`s past `data`.  From a beginning and a total size, we find the end of `data`, and so we copy everything in `data` from the beginning to the end.

Comment: @David Thornley WOW, YOUR ANSWER IS SIMPLY EYE OPENING! GOSH! What should i say! PERFECT! THANK YOU!

Comment: @iamcreasy: Whatever you say, say it quieter.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pointer to the imaginary element beyond the last element of the array. The `sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0])` yields the number of elements in `data` array. `deque` constructor accepts "iterator to the first element" and "iterator beyond the last element" (that's what `end()` iterator yields). This construct effectively computes the same as what `.end()` iterator would yield.